# Matlab Vectorization : How to avoid this "for" loop?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have following matrices :

```
X=1 2 3  
Y=4 5 6  

A=1 2 3  
  4 5 6  
  7 8 9
```

I Want to do

```
for each (i,j) in A  
  v = A(i,j)*X - Y
  B(i,j) = v * v'
```

i.e. each element of A is multiplied by vector X, then resultant vector subtracts Y from itself and finally we take inner product of that vector to bring a single number.
Can it be done without for loop ?

Comment: Might you mean `A(i,j)*X(i)` instead of A(i,j)*X?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing often forgotten in Matlab: The operator `'` takes the **conjugate transposed** (`.'` is the ordinary transposed). In other words, `A' == conj(trans(A))`, whereas `A.' == trans(A)`, which makes a difference if `A` is a complex matrix.

Ok, let's apply some mathematics to your equations. We have

```
v = A(i,j)*X - Y
B(i,j) = v * v'
       = (A(i,j)*X - Y) * (A(i,j)*X - Y)'
       = A(i,j)*X * conj(A(i,j))*X' - Y * conj(A(i,j))*X' 
         - A(i,j)*X * Y' + Y * Y'
       = A(i,j)*conj(A(i,j)) * X*X' - conj(A(i,j)) * Y*X' - A(i,j) * X*Y' + Y*Y'
```

So a first result would be

```
B = A.*conj(A) * (X*X') - conj(A) * (Y*X') - A * (X*Y') + Y*Y'
```

In the case of **real matrices/vectors**, one has the identities

```
X*Y' == Y*X'
A == conj(A)
```

which means, you can reduce the expression to

```
B = A.*A * (X*X') - 2*A * (X*Y') + Y*Y'
  = A.^2 * (X*X') - 2*A * (X*Y') + Y*Y'
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method:

```
X = [1 2 3]
Y = [4 5 6]
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]

V = bsxfun(@minus, A(:)*X, [4 5 6])
b = sum((V.^2)')
B = reshape(b , 3, 3)
```

I get the result:

```
B = 27     5    11
    45   107   197
   315   461   635
```